# How to have mod_rewrite validate cookie from different server, same domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookies

I have two server, foo.example.com and bar.example.com. They are on two different servers but on the same domain. On foo.example.com I have the page on there create a cookie using

```
setcookie('name','value',time()+3600,'/','example.com',1)
```

and it gets created just as expected.

On bar.example.com I need to restrict access to only those with that cookie and if it's not there to redirect to a custom 403 page that tells the user they need to log into foo.example.com. This is the rewrite rule I have.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !name=value [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error/403.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error/403.html [R,NC,L]
```

But I keep on getting the `403` page even though the cookie exists and has the correct domain listed and values are correct.

What is wrong with this code? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?